# How to get filesystem path to image cached with SDWebImage (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiimage, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for image caching at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) in my iOS app.

Everything is fine, however, when user scrolls fast over the collection view there is always little pause before placeholder is replaced with the cached image. I believe this is due to cache checks. For better user experience I would like cells to show the proper image instead of placeholder once an image is actually cached. This would be easy if I could get local (device) filesystem's path of the cached image and store it at the *Show* instance, and use it (if exists) instead of my placeholder.

There is the possibility to [pass success block to the *setImageWithURL* method](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView+WebCache.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:success:failure:) However, the only argument it gets is [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance (actually in master branch there is also *BOOL* variable called *cached* being passed too). So - is there a possibility to get image's filesystem path straight from the *UIImage* instance? Or should I modify *SDWebImage* so it pass that information along to cached instance? Or is there any better way achieve a goal I described earlier?

My *Show* class has *imageURL* and here is how show cell use SDWebImage:

```c
#import "ShowCell.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@implementation ShowCell

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize label = _label;
@synthesize show = _show;

- (void)setShow:(Show *)show
{
    if (_show != show) {
        self.label.text = show.title;
        if (show.imageURL) {
            [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:show.imageURL]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        }
        _show = show;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, see: [SDWebImage showing placeholder for images in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034283/sdwebimage-showing-placeholder-for-images-in-cache/15098982#15098982)

Basically I forked the project to resolve this.

**Update:**

You can just do this to avoid the flickering (this works with the master branch of the project):

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:imageView.image options:0 
 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"QuestionMarkFace.png"];
 } completed:nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

There are private `SDImageCache` methods to get filesystem path to cached image. We can make these methods public with a category. Just put the code below into the, say, `SDImageCache+Private.h` and add it to your project:

```
#import "SDImageCache.h"

@interface SDImageCache (PrivateMethods)

- (NSString *)defaultCachePathForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSString *)cachedFileNameForKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

Comment: Great Answer! thanks! I also needed to turn use those two functions like below to get my file url:   
`SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];  
NSArray *arrayOfPathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [imageCache defaultCachePathForKey:imageUrlString],[imageCache cachedFileNameForKey:imageUrlString],nil];  
NSString* path = [NSString pathWithComponents: arrayOfPathComponents];  
NSURL *urlOfTheLocalFile = [NSURL   fileURLWithPath: path];`

Comment: Not sure, but, as I remember, in modern versions of SDWebImage these methods are already public. Just did not check this out. Anyway, glad it helps.

Comment: What is the key? The full url??

Comment: @Jonny Yes, the full http url of the image.

Comment: Actually the current version of **SDImageCache** has public method *cachePathForKey()* which gives you full path to the image file with that key.