# Get unique Image file path in application Directory (Cache) w.r.t unique URL of images stored at server in SDWEBIMAGE

Tags: ios, iphone, filepath, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWEBIMAGE` library for show images in `ImageView` in my app.

I am stuck in find unique file path of stored image in cache by `SDWEBIMAGE`.  I need a file path of particular Image w.r.t it's URL in cached images in Document Directory of app.

So, imagepath must be unique for every URL.

I was go through this [This Discussion](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/339) link But no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage):

> To lookup the cache, you use the queryDiskCacheForKey:done: method. If
>   the method returns nil, it means the cache doesn't currently own the
>   image. You are thus responsible for generating and caching it. The
>   cache key is an application unique identifier for the image to cache.
>   It is generally the absolute URL of the image.

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"myNamespace"];
 [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:myCacheKey done:^(UIImage *image)
 {
     // image is not nil if image was found
 }];
```

**UPDATE**

You can get the path to your image like this:

```
NSString *myImgKey;//this is the key for the image you want the path for
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] defaultCachePathForKey:myImgKey];
```

in case you do not use the default location, you can use:

```
- (NSString *)cachePathForKey:(NSString *)key inPath:(NSString *)path;
```

This function returns the path for a certain key, but you will have to pass it your cache's root folder.

Comment: [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:myCacheKey done:^(UIImage *image) Gives me "image", But how can i get PATH of each image??

Comment: However, that you need the path tells me that you may be doing something the difficult way. What are you intending to do?

Comment: I want to Do OPEN IN Functionality in My app. Though I have done it by different way, I want to learn about path of Images w.r.t it's URL. It looks Ok so i am giving UPVOTE to it. After test it, If it works well then i will accept your answer.

Comment: Hallo simplebob, The Method you have suggested is Private Method. So How can i access name of images from Other Class??

Comment: @SharmaVishal I have rechecked, the functions are not private? which one do you think is private?

Comment: (remember that in ObjC `-`at the start of the function declaration just means "not static")

Answer (score 1):

SDwebImage always encrypt your image name. But if you want to access the image you can use your URL as the key to read the image from SDWebImage (- (UIImage *)imageFromDiskCacheForKey:(NSString *)key;). See the SDWebImageCache.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h

Still if you want to access the path you can create the category of SDWebImageCache and use private method

- (NSString *)defaultCachePathForKey:(NSString *)key

See - [How to get filesystem path to image cached with SDWebImage (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768264/how-to-get-filesystem-path-to-image-cached-with-sdwebimage-ios)

Comment: This method return me "UIImage", But how can i find Path of each image ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `encode` instead of `encrypt`, there is a big difference.

Comment: @Zaph, I need to access images saved in "com.hackemist.SDWebImageCache.default" in "Library" Directory of my Application. please provide any document or any guidance regarding it.

Comment: Thanx man, I have Accepted Above answer, So i am just able to Upvote your answer.