# SDWebImage - How to change the cache directory of the sharedImageCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, sdwebimage

As iOS can spontaneously remove the cache folder it seems like a bad idea to save the cached images in the cache folder since the SDWebImage cache mechanism knows when and which image to remove.

This happens a lot to our users, where they suddenly need to redownload all the images in the app even if it an image they downloaded 5 minutes ago.

How can I change the location of the cache of the sharedImageCached? and how to migrate the current cache to the new folder?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768264/how-to-get-filesystem-path-to-image-cached-with-sdwebimage-ios

Comment: @koen it doesn't, but I got my answer here https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/3050